# y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (2603, 2) instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

train = pd.read_csv("train_final.csv")
y = train['Y']
YValues = []
for x in range(len(y)):
    YValues.append(y[x])
print(YValues)
print(type(YValues))
YVal = np.array(YValues)


train = train.drop(['Y'], axis=1)
test = pd.read_csv("test_final.csv")

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train, label = y)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(test)

xgb2_hyperparams = XGBClassifier()
xgb2_hyperparams = xgb2.predict_proba(test)
xgb2_hyperparams_test = xgb2.predict_proba(train)
print('Accuracy: ', roc_auc_score(YVal, xgb2_hyperparams_test))
np.savetxt("xgboostHyperParams.csv", xgb2_hyperparams, delimiter=",")
print(xgb2_hyperparams)
```

I've explicitly created YVal to be a 1D np-array but it is still saying that YVal is an array of shape (2603, 2) and I'm not sure what is up with that. I originally tried fiddling with y but that led to more errors and at this point, I'm not sure why Python is so adamant about the (2603, 2) shape - I'm not sure what I'm missing that it is always reading it as (2603, 2) no matter whether it is data type series, ndarray or array.

Comment: try `y = train['Y'].squeeze()` to enforce the singular dimension.

Comment: I added it and it is still throwing the same error that ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (2603, 2) instead.

Comment: Can you print the value of y? maybe train["Y"] has two dimensions already.

Comment: y = train['Y'].squeeze()
print(y.shape)

gives a dimension of (2603, )

Comment: What's even more annoying is that in roc_auc_score, if I add something such as YVal[:, 0], it throws the error IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed

Comment: what gives `y = train['Y'] print(y.shape)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert it to an array. Pandas essentially creates a container around your data. Try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import xgboost as xgb
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

train = pd.read_csv("train_final.csv")
y = train['Y'].values
YValues = []
for x in range(len(y)):
    YValues.append(y[x])
print(YValues)
print(type(YValues))
YVal = np.array(YValues)


train = train.drop(['Y'], axis=1).values
test = pd.read_csv("test_final.csv")

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(train, label = y)
dtest = xgb.DMatrix(test)

xgb2_hyperparams = XGBClassifier()
xgb2_hyperparams = xgb2.predict_proba(test)
xgb2_hyperparams_test = xgb2.predict_proba(train)
print('Accuracy: ', roc_auc_score(YVal, xgb2_hyperparams_test))
np.savetxt("xgboostHyperParams.csv", xgb2_hyperparams, delimiter=",")
print(xgb2_hyperparams)
```